# How to do matrix and vector math in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, math, matrix, vector

I need to do matrix and vector math in Objective-C. Are there tutorials which show how this works? Are there math libraries that come in handy?

Comment: Note that the new CoreMotion system, does a heckovalot of Quaternions and the like, for you.  It's great.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since iOS 4.0, the SDK includes Apple's [Accelerate framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/), which contains a number of C matrix and vector functions that are especially optimized to run on iOS hardware.

The function names and documentation is kind of cryptic, but if performance is particularly important, it might be your best choice.

Comment: In particular, the vDSP library within the Accelerate framework is what you're looking for in regards to accelerated matrix manipulation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009464

Answer (score 3):

I did not see it mentioned but [GLKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKit_Collection/_index.html) provides vector / matrix functions for math types commonly used in computer graphics.

Comment: These are nice and straightforward to use, but I'm not clear on whether they're optimal for performance. e.g. is [GLKVector3Normalize](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKVector3/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/GLKVector3Normalize) just doing `1.0/sqrtf(x*x + y*y + z*z)`, running a [fast software approximation](http://www.google.com/search?q=0x5f3759df), or using a hardware instruction (presuming ARM even has an rsqrt)?

Comment: As far as optimal goes, it's inline'd and a few of the more expensive matrix functions have `#defines` to switch the implementation to use vectored instructions when building for the device.  Gives you an understandable matrix / vector lib with performance.  I guess everything is an approximation within the limits of the underlying storage type but pointing out Carmack fast squares to someone looking for a library could be a bit early in the journey.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the Accelerate framework that Ole points out for accelerated matrix math, both the CGAffineTransform and CATransform3D structures are matrices (3x3 and 4x4, respectively).  Apple provides helper functions for manipulating these using rotation, scaling, etc., which can be useful if you want to do these kind of transformations.

In particular, Apple has a section of the Quartz 2D Programming Guide where they [explain some of the matrix math](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-CJBECIAD).

Answer (score 0):

[YCMatrix](https://github.com/yconst/YCMatrix) provides a convenient wrapper for many of the Accelerate Framework's functions (BLAS, LAPACK and vDSP), both on OS X and iOS.

(disclaimer: I am the developer of that library)